# White Blank Screen after Splash Page - PhoneGap Application

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova

I have made an application based on PhoneGap and it works fine on my mobiles I have tried on many like Samsung A5, Huawei, Galaxy S4, Sony Xperia and many and it works fine, whereas my client says it always shows a white screen he tested on Galaxy S5, 6 and 7. I am not sure why it is so, he has sent me a video too here is [the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0na03curau08629/File%202016-09-12%2C%2008%2046%2020.mov?dl=0).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What version of mobile are you testing on ? And which version is your client working on? Are there any other plugins are you using within app. What does your app do ? Just debug ur client app using chrome://inspect and check console error. If you can post error It would be easy to figure out the problem